# Indexing for OR statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL statement

```
select id 
from table 
where  (   p1_user_id='username' 
        or p2_user_id='username' 
        or p3_user_id='username' 
        or p4_user_id='username') 
  and turn=0 
  and timestamp > 20200101
```

There are indexes on all the fields mentioned in the where clause (for reasons other than this query).

When this query runs, it doesn't use the indexes. Using explain, it shows the possible indexes, but then doesn't select one.

For testing purposes I added an additional index which is a combination of p1_user_id, p2_user_id, p3_user_id, p4_user_id.

testing this provided the same result, no index actually used.

How do I either index this in a way that will be more efficient , as reading the whole table which is what it is doing now, is obviously not efficient.

Alternatively, is there a way to rewrite the query that would be more efficient ?

edit: Would using 4 union all statements be more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you please provide a copy of the EXPLAIN? Also, UNION ALL probably is more efficient but you'd have to test to compare.

Answer (score 1):

**The best approach is "normalize your data".**

---

If you cannot or don't want by some reason then try to use 4 separate queries and combine their outputs using UNION:

```
    select id 
    from table 
    where  p1_user_id='username' 
      and turn=0 
      and timestamp > 20200101
UNION 
    select id 
    from table 
    where  p2_user_id='username' 
      and turn=0 
      and timestamp > 20200101
UNION 
    select id 
    from table 
    where  p3_user_id='username' 
      and turn=0 
      and timestamp > 20200101
UNION 
    select id 
    from table 
    where  p4_user_id='username' 
      and turn=0 
      and timestamp > 20200101
```

Each separate query can use index (`(pX_user_id, turn, timestamp)` or `(turn, pX_user_id, timestamp)` are the most suitable), i.e. for total improvement you need to create 4 separate indices. Of course final UNION  will cause filesort, but, if the final amount of output rows is not too huge then you may have an improvement totally (but may not - be ready).

---

> When this query runs, it doesn't use the indexes. Using explain, it shows the possible indexes, but then doesn't select one.

Server can use the index only as compact table version, not as an index - but for this the index must be covering, i.e. it must look similar to `(turn, timestamp, p1_user_id, p2_user_id, p3_user_id, p4_user_id, id)` - but I doubt that this is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

A classic problem.  The solution is to avoid spraying an array across columns.

Instead, have a table with `other_id` and `user_id`.  Then it becomes a trivial lookup in that table for `"username"`, then `JOIN` to the 'other' table for the other stuff.

Yes, Akina's answer works.

Yes, Rolando's answer works.

Which of the three works best for you?  It is hard to tell without more knowledge of the values (fulltext has some limitations), data distribution (whether `timestamp` is an important part of the filtering), etc.

Answer (score 0):

There would be two nifty approachess you could take with this

## APPROACH #1 : Add an Index on all the Columns

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX multicolumn_ndx
(timestamp,p1_user_id,p2_user_id,p3_user_id,,p4_user_id);
```

Try running you original query with this index present.

Check the EXPLAIN plan with your original query.

This should create an index only scan rather than a full table scan.

## APPROACH #2 : Fulltext Index + Query Rewrite

Create Full Text Index

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT multicolumn_ftndx
(p1_user_id,p2_user_id,p3_user_id,,p4_user_id);
```

Change your query to search for "username" in all four columns simultaneously

```
SELECT id FROM
(
    select id,timestamp from table where
    MATCH(p1_user_id,p2_user_id,p3_user_id,,p4_user_id)
    AGAINST ('+"username"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) A WHERE timestamp > 20200101;
```

NOTE: I refactored the query to run FULLTEXT search first and then scan returned timestamps.